# Error launching the openni_tracker

Tags: kinect, openi-tracker, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am new in Ubuntu and ROS.
The system I am using is ROS Fuerte. It is running in the Ubuntu 12.04 Lts.

When I try to open the openni_tracker I get the following error message:

"[rospack] Error: stack / package openni_tracker not found."

Some months - doing the same procedures - I could normally run the openni_tracker. What might be happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51367/error-launching-the-openni_tracker/) by [pedrohematos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3889/pedrohematos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the openni_tracker is not in your ROS package path. Did you source the correct setup.bash file (The one that you used at the time when it worked)?

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1